# javascript json not displaying all entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a very basic json file that I am loading with jquery / javascript.  Right now I am just trying to alert some of my data.  The problem I am having is that I have 3 main items in my JSON file (called "category"), but for some reason you can only read the last one.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"category":{
    "name":"Caribbean Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
},
"category":{
    "name":"European Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "2",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
},
"category":{
    "name":"U.S. Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "3",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
}
```

}

I call up the json file and alert some information like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("news.json",
    function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        //alert(data.category.article.id);
    });
```

});

So when I view the data, alls I see is the very last Category information (U.S. Travel).  It doesn't show the top 2 at all.  And I can't reference them using data.category[1] or anything like that.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Use an array. Property names should be unique.

Comment: Try doing a   'console.log(data)'   and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json file should look like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Caribbean Travel",
    "articles": [{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }]
}, {
    "name": "European Travel",
    "articles": [{
        "id": "2",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }]
}, {
    "name": "U.S. Travel",
    "articles": [{
        "id": "3",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }]
}]
```

`data[0]` will be the first category, `data[1]` the second one etc.

```
alert(data[0].articles[0].id) //alert first category's first article's id
alert(data[2].name) //alert third category's name
alert(data[1].articles[0].body) //alert second category's first article's body
alert(data[2].articles[1].body) //alert third category's second article's body
```

Comment: Alright that worked, but what if I have multiple articles for each name?  How do i access the second / third / etc articles?  data[0].article[0].id doesn't compute.

Comment: @Nick ah, let me fix that. There is now support for multiple articles, you simply use an array there as well. Note I use `articles` because it's an array that contains 0-n articles, so the naming matches better.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"category":[
{
    "name":"Caribbean Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
},
{
    "name":"European Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "2",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
},
{
    "name":"U.S. Travel",
    "article":{
        "id": "3",
        "title": "",
        "teaser": "",
        "image": "",
        "date": "",
        "map": "",
        "body": ""
    }
}
]
}
```